# Why is meters/second the same as meters per second?

Tags: velocity, dimensional-analysis

In quantities such as speed where the derived (SI) unit is m/s, why do we pronounce it and interpret it as meters **per** second? My guess is that 1 m is associated with 1 second. Similarly, 5 m/s is pronounced and interpreted as 5 meters per second, because 5 meters are associated with 1 second. I am not sure whether this view is naive.

Comment: 5 meters *per* second means 5 meters *for each* second, i.e. every second an object with that speed moves by 5 meters. What is not clear about that? Similarly, 50% (50 *per* 100) is 50/100, that is 0.5

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be more about English language use than about physics.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin That makes sense. It is the case that we can always translate a/b to 'a' per 'b' and vice versa in Mathematics and Physics?

Comment: I wouldn't say always. For instance, it would be unnatural to read "1/2" as "1 per 2." In my mind, reading "a/b" as "a per b" would be unnatural unless it is known to be a rate of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an instantaneous value.  The speed, in m/s (or any other unit) is:

$$\frac{ds}{dt} $$

where $s$ is distance/displacement.  If speed is constant, it really doesn't matter: an object moving at 5 m/s will cover 5 m in every second.

It will be very different if the speed varies.  Imagine a dropping stone, subject to a 10m/s/s acceleration.  At 1 s, the instantaneous speed is 10 m/s, but that speed occurs for exactly zero time.